# Display resolution problem with vaio vgc-js160j

Tags: display

First off all, iv'e searched the web and solved the initial problems like selecting the right resolution that is 1680-1050. Still, this black line in the right side of the screen is still there, and that part of the desktop is not shown (because of the black line). I had to xrandr another resolution to manage to use the computer that is 1600-1050 and save it, so the computer is usable. Now I really need help to finally eliminate that black line and use the whole screen. Please help, I'm not an expert, but I really dislike windows and have been using linux for a couple of years.

[Here is an image of how the problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlwyt.jpg)

[These are the spects of my cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUtOW.png)

```
 $ lspci | egrep "VGA|Video|3D" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

[Here is a picture of what it showed me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7yD0.jpg)

Comment: What video adapter (GPU) do you have? Please add output of `lspci | egrep "VGA|Video|3D"`to the question.

Comment: So it uses Intel, I guess with open-source drivers. You can try to boot system with [`nomodeset` option](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/66509).

Comment: Thanks again, I will try and notify if it worked.

Comment: The you can try to temporarily rename your `~/.profile` with `mv ~/.profile ~/.profile_bkp` and try again.

Comment: i've done what you told me, and I posted a picture for you to see. In a very brief way, it does not recognize the size of the monitor.

Comment: Currently I do not have new ideas, I'm sorry.

Comment: I've did it again, but still no luck. How can the OS recognize the resolution? It says that it is WSXGA+. Maybe that is something that is not common. Still, I want to resolve this problem. I like the OS. Where can I look for information?

Comment: You need to read something like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Adding_undetected_resolutions .

Comment: Another observation is that for some reason ubuntu detects 2 screens; LVDS and VGA. But the thing is that VGA does not exist. Maybe that has something to do.